# Console CPU utilisation chart

Tags: monitoring, performance

I need to monitor CPU and network utilisation from a terminal.

For network traffic, I have found the perfect tool: [slurm](https://github.com/mattthias/slurm/wiki).
It gives me a moving chart. It gives me an nCurses-like UI I can use from a tty.

Here's a [screenshot](http://screenshots.debian.net/package/slurm):
[image: slurm 0.3.3 on Falce]

Is there a slurm equivalent showing CPU utilisation?

Comment: `htop`? Though it's not as pretty/big as slurm's chart, see the second PNG from bottom at http://htop.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=screenshots

Comment: That's what I use at the moment: htop. And I love it for process monitoring. For utilisation _charts_? ASCII art just doesn't cut it, does it?

Comment: nmon might help.

Answer (score 19):

I couldn't find a live, text-only CPU chart either.  So, I made one.

Here's a link to my github repo: https://github.com/rigel314/ttysys

Try it out if you like, and please report any errors on my repo's [issues](https://github.com/rigel314/ttysys/issues) page.

EDIT:

#### Screenshot:

[image: ttysys example]

#### Install:

You will have to compile it from source.  I provided a simple makefile that calls gcc.

You can run the program using `make` then `./build/target/ttysys`
Alternatively, you can run `make install` followed by `ttysys` since it is in your path now.

#### Usage:

`$ ttysys [<sequence>]`

*sequence* can consist of any number of the following characters:

- `?` - Displays a help window.
- `h` - Split current window horizontally.
- `v` - Split current window vertically.
- `c` - Close current window.
- Tab - Move to next window in order of creation.
- Arrow Keys - Move to next window on screen in direction pressed.
- Numbers `0` - `9` - Select a data source for a window.

  - `0` will set the data source to an overview, and `1` - `9` set it to a specific core.
- `g` - Toggle grid for selected window.
- `e` - Toggle value display in current window's title.
- `t` - Toggle display of current window's title bar.
- `l` - Toggle display of current window's label sidebar.
- `q` - Quit this program.
- `u` - Same as pressing up arrow key. Move to window above current one.
- `d` - Same as pressing down arrow key. Move to window below current one.
- `l` - Same as pressing left arrow key. Move to window left of current one.
- `r` - Same as pressing right arrow key. Move to window right of current one.

These same buttons will control the program while it is running.

#### How it works:

It works by reading the first few lines in `/proc/stat` that begin with cpu.
`man 5 proc` explained the meaning of contents of `/proc/stat`.
These lines tell you how much time each CPU spent in different states.  The sum of each line is the total time spent for each CPU.  I read this file twice with a second in between.  Then, I subtract the two totals to have the total CPU time spent during my `sleep()`.  Now, I add the user and system numbers together and divide by my difference.  Finally, it's just a matter of displaying it nicely.

Comment: Nice work. Could you include a screenshot here and also a bit more about the tool? We like answers to be able to stand on their own and not just be links. Great job on the tool BTW.

Comment: Good job. I've made one myself although much less features. None to be exact :) https://github.com/mnmnc/cpuchart

Comment: Try: `ttysys hvm$'\t'v$'\t'1h$'\t'3h$'\t'2$'\t'4` for a quad core CPU.

Comment: `r`,`l`,`u`, and `d` can be used in the argument for arrow keys: right, left, up, and down - so `ttysys vhmdhh1r2rh3r4` should accomplish the same result

Comment: Which occurs to me is an undocumented feature which conflicts with the incorrect documentation of `u` for unsplit, it should be `c` for close.  I should update my readme and answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

- [tload](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tload), which is typically installed by default
- [ttyload](https://github.com/lindes/ttyload) is pretty good, too

[image: ttyload screen sample]
[image: ttyload screen sample]

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Glances. I think it might fit your bill.

http://nicolargo.github.com/glances/

[image]

Comment: Looks very cool. Will have to wait until it graduates to the Ubuntu package list, though. I could use something from the standard apt-get repository (no addition of a PPA) with less functionality but full support...

Comment: No need to wait, just grab the script and run it. It looks like a single script program. If not, use `pip` to install it.

Comment: It's based on python, pretty standard.

Comment: i just installed Glances, but I only see real time info just like `top` provides. Is it also possible to chart CPU usage with Glances?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of `htop`. (http://hisham.hm/htop/)

[image]

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

Comment: `htop` has its uses, but it can't show a moving chart of CPU usage over a period of time, as described in the question. It can only show meters of the current CPU usage.

Comment: sorry but couldnt stop myself, your computers name is lulz? that's so hilarious lol ^^

Comment: No, hah. That's just an image I pulled from image search. *Someone's* computer's name is lulz though.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane At this point in time (2023) htop does have this functionality. Perhaps it didn't when you commented.  To set this, press F2, navigate to the meters in the second column, and press space bar twice. Voila!

Answer (score 3):

I use `elmon` (http://elmon.sourceforge.net/) it may draw graphs not only for the CPU. For example:
[image: Example Screenshot]